# Compare arraylists for non identical elements

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Hello there I am being confused in comparing two array lists, one of my array list is as:

```
 private ArrayList<String> members = new ArrayList<>();
 members.add("member123keyxyzmember123 number");
 members.add("member456keyxyzmember456 number");
 members.add("member789keyxyzmember789 number");
 members.add("member2233keyxyzmember2233 number");
 members.add("member1122keyxyzmember1122 number");
```

The second arraylist is as:

```
 private ArrayList<String> syncMembers = new ArrayList<>();
 syncMembers.add("member123keyxyz123statuskeyxyz123photokeyxyzmember123 number");
 syncMembers.add("member456keyxyz456statuskeyxyz456photokeyxyzmember456 number");
```

---

The problem is that I am comparing both so that they give me the numbers that are in **members** list and are not in **syncMembers** list!

That is the out put should be:

```
    member789 number
    member2233 number
    member1122 number
```

only!

---

What I have been trying is:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < members.size(); i++) {
        String stringFromMembersList = members.get(i);
        String[] memberParts = stringFromMembersList.split("keyxyz");
        String memberNumber = memberParts[1];
        //Log.e("hgax", "sync:::" + memberNumber);

        for (int j = 0; j < syncMembers.size(); j++) {
            String stringFromSyncList = syncMembers.get(j);
            String[] syncParts = stringFromSyncList.split("keyxyz");

            String n = syncParts[3];

            if (memberNumber.equals(n)) {
                //Log.e("hgax", "hee:::" + n);
                break;
            } else {
                Log.e("hgax", "ssshee:::" + memberNumber);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

The output I am getting is:

```
   member456 number
   member789 number
   member789 number
   member2233 number
   member2233 number
   member2233 number
   member1122 number
   member1122 number
   member1122 number
   member1122 number
```

I am bit confuse what is happeing to me and What i have been doing wrong? Can somebody please tell what blunder I am doing Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use a Logger or Debugger to find out?

Comment: You can't determine whether to display it until you've search the entire `syncMembers` list. You need to ensure there are no matches first, then display the member from `members` if there are no matches. Just use a `boolean` flag to decide on whether to output, update to `true` if there's a match and terminate the search of `syncMembers` early. (edited)

Comment: that was a typing mistake member456!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** updated answer to include the original mixed values in the `arrayList`

```
ArrayList<String> membersList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> syncMembersList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < members.size(); i++) {
            String s = members.get(i).substring(members.get(i).lastIndexOf("member"));
            membersList.add(s);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < syncMembers.size(); j++) {
            String s = syncMembers.get(j).substring(syncMembers.get(j).lastIndexOf("member"));
            syncMembersList.add(s);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < membersList.size(); i++) {
            if (!syncMembersList.contains(membersList.get(i))) {
                System.out.println(membersList.get(i));
            }
        }
```

This will print the output you require.

Comment: run:
member789 number
member2233 number
member1122 number
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second).

Comment: Note: I just added the Strings in syncMembers as: syncMembers.add("member123 number");
        syncMembers.add("member456 number"); to save time.

Comment: please elobrate your answer more

Comment: @TheAngelCat answer updated including the non-matching original Strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try to think about what you need to check to reach your goal. In order to determine that a member in the list `members` does not exist in `syncMembers` you have to check the entirety of the `syncMembers` list for that member. Since the lists are not identical (as your question states), you cannot use `Collection.contains(Object o)`.

This should achieve your goal:

```
// We need this initial check as if syncMembers is empty it'll display all members
// And why bother to do this if syncMembers is empty anyway!
if (!syncMembers.isEmpty()) {
    for (String member : members) {
        String memberNo = member.split("keyxyz")[1];
        int i = 0;
        boolean found = false;
        while (!found && i < syncMembers.size()) {
            // Iterate over syncMembers until a match if found
            // or we have exhausted the list
            found = syncMembers.get(i).split("keyxyz")[3].equals(memberNo);
            i++;
        }
        if (!found) {
            // Display only if not found
            System.out.println(memberNo);
        }
    }
}
```